# create a SPA using that connects to Microsoft CRM Dynamics Online trial using Web API?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm-online

Is there a way to use create a SPA that connects to Microsoft CRM Dynamics Online trial using Web API? I am not sure how you register the client. as you need an AD that is in an Azure account that is associated to the O365 trial.

If anyone can point me the right direction to achieve this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: According to the [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595797.aspx) page in the SDK, you can use trials for everything.  Have you seen it?

Answer (score 0):

You're using webservices, AngularJS (as SPA framework) consumes the webservice directly without any need for authentication.

If you want to register the client via login/password authenticaiton , you can use the built-in $interceptor service to inject those credentials into the requests , same for webtokens.